# Magento 2: How to create customer from admin with unconfirmed email and send email confirmation?

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to create a customer from admin, but after creating a customer it shows the email is confirmed. I want the email to be unconfirmed until the customer clicks on the email confirmation link.